# Why do we need zero voltage reference circuit for micro-controller?

Tags: power-electronics, thyristor

I am designing a circuit for controlling triac firing angle. For controlling purpose i'll be needing a micro-controller. Now the confusion is why do i need zero voltage reference circuit for micro-controller? What its usage and how we can design this zero voltage reference circuit?

P.S: I am using Arduino Uno which consist of ATMEGA328P ic. 
Pls answer in a layman language. 
Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Thge way a triac firing angle controller works is to delay the firing time of the triac a controlled time (or angle, with a known duration of a mains cycle, time is related to angle) **after the zero crossing of the mains cycle**.

You need to know when to start timing. That's the time at which the mains voltage passes through zero volts. How do you know when it passes through zero?